# iphone xcode sqlite3_open remote host

Tags: iphone, xcode

i try to get a connection my server, with the sqlite3_open command!

my question...is it possible to that? i got the following code...

```
 // Get the path to the documents directory and append the databaseName
 databaseName = @"AnimalDatabase.sql";
 NSString *serverpath = @"http://localhost/app/";

 databasePath = [serverpath stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];


and then this here

-(void) readAnimalsFromDatabase {
 // Setup the database object
 sqlite3 *database;

 // Init the animals Array
 animals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 // Open the database from the users filessytem
 if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
  // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
  const char *sqlStatement = "select * from animals";
  sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
  if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
   // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
   while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    // Read the data from the result row
    NSString *aName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
    NSString *aDescription = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
    NSString *aImageUrl = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];

    // Create a new animal object with the data from the database
    Animal *animal = [[Animal alloc] initWithName:aName description:aDescription url:aImageUrl];

    // Add the animal object to the animals Array
    [animals addObject:animal];

    [animal release];
   }
  }
  // Release the compiled statement from memory
  sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

 }
 sqlite3_close(database);

}
```

any suggestion??

Answer (score 0):

Where you get the idea that SQLite can open database from URL??
It can open files only (or, create temporary db in memory).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is just **NO**, there are lot of mistakes in your code anyway. For example:

```
databaseName = @"AnimalDatabase.sql";
```

Where did you get this. iPhone is working with sqlite database, it has nothing in common with sql files:)